# Many to Many Nested Relationship as List in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm building an API using the Django Rest Framework and I have two models that share a many to many relationship. The models are Contacts and Tasks. A Task can be shared with several Contacts and a Contact can have many Tasks shared with it. I'm also using a manual join table, rather than Django's built-in many-to-many relationship.

In the API, I'd like to have the method for retrieving Tasks include a list of Contacts with whom the Task has been shared. I have a way of accomplishing this currently, but it isn't great. The serialized Task has an attribute `shared_with`, which is a related field that goes through the `SharedWithSerializer` class (which is the version of the ContactTaskJoin serializer for this side of the relationship). So the output is quite clunky. The `SharedWithSerializer` has just one attribute—`contact`—which references the `ContactSerializer` class. An example Task returned by the API:

```
{
 'id': 100,
 'shared_with': [
    {
       'contact': {
          'id': 1,
          'name': 'Alice'
       }
    },
    {
       'contact': {
          'id': 2,
          'name': 'Bob'
       }
    }
 ]
}
```

What I would like is to just have a plain list of the Contacts with whom the Task was shared. Something like:

```
 {
 'id': 100,
 'shared_with': [
    {
       'id': 1,
       'name': 'Alice'
    },
    {
       'id': 2,
       'name': 'Bob'
    },
 ]
}
```

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Post the code please and we should be able to help more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could override `to_representation` on the `SharedWithSerializer` to flatten the contact fields one level up

For example

```
class SharedWithSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    def to_representation(self, obj):
        representation = super().to_representation(obj)
        shared_with = representation.pop('shared_with')
        representation['shared_with'] = [entry['contact'] for entry in shared_with]
        return representation
```

I hope this helps resolve you issue. If you could also post your models.py and serializers.py I can provide a more tailored answer, if necessary.